# git pull isn't possible, there are unmerged files

Tags: git

I've read many other questions on this, and most answers involve doing git reset --hard origin/master, which makes us lose all of our committed changes, which i can NOT afford to do.

The following is the error message I receive in terminal:

[image]

How do I fix this? I just want to import the upstream version of master into my local master, and then push my changes to the upstream master. I know git reset --hard upstream/master will import the upstream changes to my local master, but I do not want to lose all my changes I've made.

Comment: Use `git stash` to temporarily stash the files and `git stash apply` to bring hem back after you've pulled. Also, you probably shouldn't be checking in `.DS_Store` files

Comment: To follow-up on Nick's comment: you may want to add `.DS_Store` to your `.gitignore` file, or, probably better (since it's system dependent), to your `$HOME/.git-core.excludesfile` file.

Comment: Likely, in this case it would be better to resolve the merge conflict first, and only then go on with the next merge. As far as I know, .DS_Store isn't a file which changes you could wish to merge from different branches. That's why you should _remove_ that file from git control with `git rm -f .DS_Store` and _then_ add it to the list of ignored.

Comment: Simple addition of the file to the list of ignored won't help because git already tracks it, effectively ignoring corresponding entry in .gitignore, .git/info/exclude and other configs

Answer (score 0):

```
# save your changed files in a stash that behaves like a stack
git stash

# Pull changes from upstream
git pull origin master

# get the changed files from stash and apply to the current branch
git stash apply
```

Comment: Why apply, and not pop?

Comment: apply and pop both get the changed files from the stash.
 The main difference is that apply won't remove from stash, while pop may remove from the stash if there's no conflict.
It's important to notice that git stash pop may not remove from the stash in case of conflict, this may lead the user reapplying something from the stash that he/she thought had been removed.
git stash apply seems more predictable and easy to use, after everything is okay you can simply git stash drop.